# Ruby gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I started in Ruby recently. And I'm having trouble installing a gem .

I use this command :

```
gem install ocra-1.3.4
```

What am I doing wrong ? The gem file is in the same place the batch.

Comment: Try this: `gem install ocra --local`

Comment: You should say what error are you getting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i use `gem install ocra` the latest version is being installed, version 1.3.4
If you want another version you do it like this

```
C:\devkit>gem install ocra -v 1.3.1
Successfully installed ocra-1.3.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ocra-1.3.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for ocra-1.3.1...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your syntax. The correct way to install a specific version of a gem is by appending the `-v` of `--version` option followed by its numeric identifier.

In your case, any of the following should do it:

```
gem install ocra -v 1.3.1
gem install ocra -v=1.3.1
gem install ocra --version 1.3.1
```

You may want to append the `--verbose` option (`gem install ocra --version 1.3.1 --verbose`). It enables some sort of debug mode so you can see exactly what's happening and where any problem are.